# How to delete a rows with list of primary keys in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, delete-row

In SQL:

```
delete from table where (pk1,pk2) IN (('1',2),('2',3))
```

What would be the similar syntax in `sqlite` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since Sqlite does not seem to support `IN` queries with pairs, the most straight forward and readable query you can do is probably (brackets added for readability);

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE (pk1='1' AND pk2=2) OR (pk1='2' AND pk2=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

One possiblity is to use correlated query:

```
WITH cte(p1, p2) AS(
  VALUES ('1',2)
  UNION ALL VALUES ('2', 3))         -- add more pairs if needed
DELETE FROM tab
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte WHERE pk1 = p1 AND pk2 = p2);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9c21a/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: what if user has to delete thousands of rows?

Comment: @saimadan Then he needs to add more pairs. The same as using `IN` or multiple `AND OR` conditions. Anyway deleting thousand of paris probably he could write condition more concisely  using `BETWEEN/>/<` operators.